# Extract lines from indented output

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, regular-expression

I'd like to parse parses the output below (from ddcutil) in a shell command:

```
Model: MQ780
MCCS version: 2.1
Commands:
   Op Code: 01 (VCP Request)
   Op Code: 02 (VCP Response)
   Op Code: 03 (VCP Set)
   Op Code: 0C (Save Settings)
   Op Code: E3 (Capabilities Reply)
   Op Code: F3 (Capabilities Request)
VCP Features:
   Feature: 02 (New control value)
   Feature: 04 (Restore factory defaults)
   Feature: 05 (Restore factory brightness/contrast defaults)
   Feature: 08 (Restore color defaults)
   Feature: 10 (Brightness)
   Feature: 12 (Contrast)
   Feature: 14 (Select color preset)
      Values:
         05: 6500 K
         08: 9300 K
         0b: User 1
   Feature: 16 (Video gain: Red)
   Feature: 18 (Video gain: Green)
   Feature: 1A (Video gain: Blue)
   Feature: 52 (Active control)
   Feature: 60 (Input Source)
      Values:
         11: HDMI-1
         12: HDMI-2
         0f: DisplayPort-1
         10: DisplayPort-2
   Feature: AC (Horizontal frequency)
   Feature: AE (Vertical frequency)
   Feature: B2 (Flat panel sub-pixel layout)
   Feature: B6 (Display technology type)
   Feature: C0 (Display usage time)
   Feature: C6 (Application enable key)
   Feature: C8 (Display controller type)
   Feature: C9 (Display firmware level)
   Feature: D6 (Power mode)
      Values:
         01: DPM: On,  DPMS: Off
         04: DPM: Off, DPMS: Off
```

and I'm trying to extract "Feature: 60" values so that I can pipe them to another script:

```
11: HDMI-1
12: HDMI-2
0f: DisplayPort-1
10: DisplayPort-2
```

Is there an elegant way to do this? I came up with the regex below but am thinking there must be a better way:

```
$ sudo ddcutil capabilities | pcregrep -M -o2 "(?s)(Feature: 60.*?Values:)(.*?)(Feature)"
```

If the output was in json I could have used `jq` and I think there's `yq` for yaml but I can't make it accept this as yaml.

Comment: Maybe use `getvcp` instead of `capabilities` to get just the feature code you're interested in?

Comment: that seems to return the currently active option rather than list of possible options.

Comment: And I'm more interested in learning about ways to solve this pattern rather than ddcutil per se

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/bin/perl
while(<>) {
   if (/Feature: 60/) {
     while(<>) {
       last if (/Feature/);
       next if (/Values/);
       print $_, "\n";
     }
   }
}
```

Easy :)

Answer (score 2):

Using any awk (and `cat file` inplace of `sudo ddcutil capabilities` to demonstrate the answer):

```
$ cat file |
  awk '$1=="Feature:"{f=($2 == "60"); next} $1=="Values:"{next} f{$1=$1; print}'
11: HDMI-1
12: HDMI-2
0f: DisplayPort-1
10: DisplayPort-2
```

Note the use of the full string comparison `$2 == "60"` to avoid a false match if `Feature: 607` or similar existed in your input and we used `/Feature: 60/` or similar partial comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`

```
$ sudo ddcutil capabilities | sed -En '/Feature: 60/{n;/Values:/{:a;n;/Feature:/,/Feature:/!s/^[ \t]+//gp;ba}}'
11: HDMI-1
12: HDMI-2
0f: DisplayPort-1
10: DisplayPort-2
```

Answer (score 1):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$ raku -ne 'if / \s* Feature \: \s 60 \s / {  
               for lines() { 
                 last if /Feature/; 
                 next if /Values/; 
                 put $_.trim-leading 
               }
             };'  file
```

Raku answer inspired by excellent Perl5 answer from @White_Owl. Surprising (to me), even when Raku's `-ne` commandline flags are used, the `for lines()` call within the code works without a hitch (helpful syntax if you've ever written erroneous `while` code).

Note: Raku has a `when` syntax which acts like a case statement:

```perl
~$ raku -ne 'if / \s* Feature \: \s 60 \s / { 
               for lines() { 
                 last when /Feature/; 
                 next when /Values/; 
                 default {put $_.trim-leading}
               }
             };'  file
```

Sample Input: as above

Sample Output:

```
 11: HDMI-1
 12: HDMI-2
 0f: DisplayPort-1
 10: DisplayPort-2
```

Finally, whitespace is trimmed from the output using `.trim-leading`.

https://docs.raku.org/language/control.html#when
https://docs.raku.org
https://raku.org

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`:

```
sudo ddcutil capabilities | awk '
    /Feature: 60/{ f=1; next }
    f { if (NF==2) print $1, $2; else if ($1=="Feature:") exit }'
```