# Merge successive lines into one line

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

In a text file, if the first 25 characters in a line are a space, how can I append that line to the previous line until another line comes along that starts with an ASCII character in column one. Since it can't be displayed like that here, I've added a screenshot[image]. In the original file, I have to remove the trailing spaces for each line first. That works, but I have no idea how to implement the rest. I would prefer the whole thing as a script (no Perl or similar)

Original file:

```
08/07/2023 09:02:07      ANR8592T Session 137576 connection is using protocol
                         TLSVI3, cipher specification TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
                         certificate TSM Self-Signed Certificate. (SESSION:
                         137576)
08/07/2023 09:02:07      ANR@B4OT Session 137576 started for administrator ADMIN
                         (WinNT) (SSL MU-SV-SPS1.de.bertrandt.net[192.168.171.56]-
                         :65234) on MU-SV-SPS1.de.bertrandt.net:1500. (SESSTON:
                         137576)
08/07/2023 09:02:07      ANR2017T Administrator ADMIN issued command: select
                         status from processes where process="NAS SnapMirror
                         Backup’ and status like 'WMU-SV-CL2%' (SESSION: 137576)
                         08/07/2023 09:02:07 ANR@46ST Session 137576 ended for administrator ADMIN
                         (WinNT). (SESSION: 137576)
08/07/2023 09:02:38      ANR8592T Session 137577 connection is using protocol
                         TLSVI3, cipher specification TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
                         certificate TSM Self-Signed Certificate. (SESSION:
                         137577)
08/07/2023 09:02:38      ANR@B4OT Session 137577 started for administrator ADMIN
                         (WinNT) (SSL MU-SV-SPS1.de.bertrandt.net[192.168.171.56]-
                         :65235) on MU-SV-SPS1.de.bertrandt.net:1560. (SESSTON:
                         137577)
08/07/2023 09:02:38      ANR2017T Administrator ADMIN issued command: select
                         node_name, filespace_name, BACKUP_START, BACKUP_END,
                         CAPACITY, PCT_UTIL from filespaces where node_name like
                         “MU-SV-CL2%" (SESSION: 137577)
08/07/2023 09:02:38      ANR@46ST Session 137577 ended for administrator ADMIN
                         (WinNT). (SESSION: 137577)
08/07/2023 09:02:38      ANR8592T Session 137578 connection is using protocol
                         TLSVI3, cipher specification TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
                         certificate TSM Self-Signed Certificate. (SESSION:
                         137578)
08/07/2023 09:02:38      ANR@B4OT Session 137578 started for administrator ADMIN
                         (WinNT) (SSL MU-SV-SPS1.de.bertrandt.net[192.168.171.56]-
                         :65236) on MU-SV-SPS1.de.bertrandt.net:1560. (SESSTON:
                         137578)
```

Requested result:

```
08/07/2023 09:02:07      ANR8592T Session 137576 connection is using protocol TLSVI3, cipher specification TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, certificate TSM Self-Signed Certificate. (SESSION: 137576)
08/07/2023 09:02:07      ANR@B4OT Session 137576 started for administrator ADMIN (WinNT) (SSL MU-SV-SPS1.de.bertrandt.net[192.168.171.56]- :65234) on MU-SV-SPS1.de.bertrandt.net:1500. (SESSTON: 137576)
08/07/2023 09:02:07      ANR2017T Administrator ADMIN issued command: select status from processes where process="NAS SnapMirror Backup’ and status like 'WMU-SV-CL2%' (SESSION: 137576) 08/07/2023 09:02:07 ANR@46ST Session 137576 ended for administrator ADMIN (WinNT). (SESSION: 137576)
08/07/2023 09:02:38      ANR8592T Session 137577 connection is using protocol TLSVI3, cipher specification TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, certificate TSM Self-Signed Certificate. (SESSION: 137577)
08/07/2023 09:02:38      ANR@B4OT Session 137577 started for administrator ADMIN (WinNT) (SSL MU-SV-SPS1.de.bertrandt.net[192.168.171.56]- :65235) on MU-SV-SPS1.de.bertrandt.net:1560. (SESSTON: 137577)
08/07/2023 09:02:38      ANR2017T Administrator ADMIN issued command: select node_name, filespace_name, BACKUP_START, BACKUP_END, CAPACITY, PCT_UTIL from filespaces where node_name like “MU-SV-CL2%" (SESSION: 137577)
08/07/2023 09:02:38      ANR@46ST Session 137577 ended for administrator ADMIN (WinNT). (SESSION: 137577)
08/07/2023 09:02:38      ANR8592T Session 137578 connection is using protocol TLSVI3, cipher specification TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, certificate TSM Self-Signed Certificate. (SESSION: 137578)
08/07/2023 09:02:38      ANR@B4OT Session 137578 started for administrator ADMIN (WinNT) (SSL MU-SV-SPS1.de.bertrandt.net[192.168.171.56]- :65236) on MU-SV-SPS1.de.bertrandt.net:1560. (SESSTON: 137578)
```

Comment: Whitespace in questions and answers can be preserved by enclosing the example text in [code blocks](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting). Quote: _The first four spaces will be stripped off, but all other whitespace will be preserved._

Comment: @OP: Perl is a scripting language, so I assume you mean _shell_ script?

Comment: This question seems similar to an earlier question with 'indented' input, for which there are "one-liner" answers written in `sed`, `awk`, `perl`, and `raku`: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/738723

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A pure bash solution

Script `format_text_purebash.sh`:

```bash
#! /usr/bin/env bash

declare -r input_filename="$1"

declare new_line=
while read -r line; do
    if [[ "$line" =~ ^[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\ [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9] ]]; then
        if [[ -n "$new_line" ]]; then
            echo "$new_line"
        fi
        new_line="$line"
    else
        new_line="$new_line $line"
    fi
done < "$input_filename"
if [[ -n "$new_line" ]]; then
    echo "$new_line"
fi
```

With:

```bash
chmod +x format_text_purebash.sh
```

Run like this:

```bash
./format_text_purebash.sh log.txt
```

Comment: You should add the usual warning for newcomers to that - [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice).

Answer (score 3):

Solution using `sed` at the end of this answer.

Use the `ed` editor to first replace all blanks (tabs or spaces) at the start of lines with a single space, and then join each line that starts with a space with the line before:

```bash
printf '%s\n' 'g/^[[:blank:]]\{1,\}/ s// /' 'g/^ / -,.j' ,p Q | ed -s file
```

The resulting document is printed to the standard output stream, but you can change `,p` to `w` to write it back to the original file.

The two main commands in this editing session:

1. `g/^[[:blank:]]\{1,\}/ s// /`
   This removes all runs of one or more blanks from the start of any line and replaces them with a single space.
2. `g/^ / -,.j`
   This joins each line that starts with a space with its previous line.

Combining these two `g` commands into a single `g` command that executes both the `s` and `j` command:

```bash
printf '%s\n' 'g/^[[:blank:]]\{1,\}/ s// /\' '-,.j' ,p Q | ed -s file
```

Testing on this example input:

```
XXX XXX XXX     YYY YYY YYY YYY YYY
                ZZZ ZZZ ZZZ ZZZ ZZZ
                YYY ZZZ YYY ZZZ YYY
                YYY ZZZ YYY ZZZ YYY
                YYY ZZZ YYY ZZZ YYY
XXX XXX XXX     YYY YYY YYY YYY YYY
                ZZZ ZZZ ZZZ ZZZ ZZZ
                YYY ZZZ YYY ZZZ YYY
XXX XXX XXX     YYY YYY YYY YYY YYY
                ZZZ ZZZ ZZZ ZZZ ZZZ
                YYY ZZZ YYY ZZZ YYY
                YYY ZZZ YYY ZZZ YYY
                YYY ZZZ YYY ZZZ YYY
```

The result:

```
XXX XXX XXX     YYY YYY YYY YYY YYY ZZZ ZZZ ZZZ ZZZ ZZZ YYY ZZZ YYY ZZZ YYY YYY ZZZ YYY ZZZ YYY YYY ZZZ YYY ZZZ YYY
XXX XXX XXX     YYY YYY YYY YYY YYY ZZZ ZZZ ZZZ ZZZ ZZZ YYY ZZZ YYY ZZZ YYY
XXX XXX XXX     YYY YYY YYY YYY YYY ZZZ ZZZ ZZZ ZZZ ZZZ YYY ZZZ YYY ZZZ YYY YYY ZZZ YYY ZZZ YYY YYY ZZZ YYY ZZZ YYY
```

It does not matter if the indentation of the indented lines is made with spaces or tabs.  Also, the spacing (whether done with spaces or tabs) between the first bit of each "section" (the `XXX...` bit in my example) and the rest is not altered.

---

With `sed`:

```bash
sed -e '/^[[:blank:]]\{1,\}/ { s///; H; $!d; }' -e 'x; y/\n/ /' file
```

This detects any line with one or more initial blanks, removes these and appends the line to the hold space (an auxiliary buffer in `sed` that is not wiped between cycles).  If the line is not the last, it is discarded, and the script skips to the next input line.

For any other line (and the last line in the document, if it starts with a blank), the buffer is swapped with the hold space and all newlines (inserted as a delimiter by the `H` command) are replaced by spaces before the result is outputted.

This produces the same output as the `ed` pipeline above but will fail to process the last line of input if it does not start with a blank (this is not the case in the example text, as far as I can make out from the image).

Answer (score 1):

A solution with awk

Script `format_text.awk`:

```bash
#! /usr/bin/awk -f

/^[0-9][0-9]\/[0-9][0-9]\/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]/ {
    if (line) {
        print line
    }
    line = $0
    next
}
{
    gsub(/^[ \t]+/, "")
    line = line " " $0
}
END {
    if (line) {
        print line
    }
}
```

With:

```bash
chmod +x format_text.awk
```

Run like this:

```bash
./format_text.awk log.txt
```

Comment: This is actually a solution in awk, not even requiring POSIX sh, much less the features of GNU Bash. The shebang could simply be changed to `#!/usr/bin/awk -f`, with the text between single quotes after the invocation of awk pasted after the shebang, and (not really necessary, but providing a clue to the user about the script type) renamed to `format_text.awk`. What's more critical though, is that in either form it duplicates lines not beginning with spaces, and doesn't join with them those that do.

Comment: @Vilinkameni, I follow you. It's a pure awk solution. I don't see any duplicate lines

Comment: This is a log of a session using the current version of the solution: http://ix.io/4DwV I'm using GNU awk 5.1.1 in Artix Linux.

Comment: This is a possible working solution: http://ix.io/4DwX (The awk script is replaced by `BEGIN{FS="\n"; RS=""} { gsub(/\n\s+/, " "); print }`.)

Comment: With your example, I have only two lines. I'm using GNU Awk 5.1.1, API: 3.1 (GNU MPFR 4.1.1-p1, GNU MP 6.2.1) on Fedora 38

Comment: I just tried the script `format_text.sh` on an Alpine 3.17 machine with GNU awk 5.1.1, with the exact same results as on Artix Linux (duplicate lines, unmerged lines).

Comment: @Vilinkameni don't use a shebang to call awk (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/61002754/1745001), don't add a suffix to a Unix command or you can't change the implementation (e.g. replace awk with perl or compiled C) without changing the calls to it, [the script you suggested](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/754032/merge-successive-lines-into-one-line/754165#comment1435184_754034) requires the input to contain no empty lines and would read all input into memory at once and would require GNU awk for the non-POSIX extension `\s`.

Comment: @EdMorton I'm not sure I understand the first sentence in your comment. The only parameter here is the pathname of the file, which gets passed to the script with the awk shebang, while I avoid the overhead of unnecessarily invoking the bloated Bash. Second, as far as I could see from the picture posted in the OP, the input contains no empty lines, and there is no requirement to use a specific version of awk (`\s` could be rewritten easily though). The rationale behind your linked answer goes against the Unix philosophy. Scripts should do one thing and work with other programs/scripts.

Comment: The only parameter **for now** is the pathname to the file. If the OP decides to add something in future (e.g. an option) they'll need to do much more than necessary if they used a shebang and may be tempted to implement it all in awk when doing some in shell may be better. The overhead is miniscule and the script is not bloated by adding a call to awk. The OP posted some sample data, that doesn't mean they don't have other data.

Comment: The rationale behind my linked answer is valid and consistent with the Unix philosophy and good engineering judgement - a script doing 1 thing doesn't mean it must only call 1 tool, and needing to require more changes if you use a shebang than if you don't demonstrates unnecessary coupling in the former case.

Comment: As you stated, any necessary parameters could be passed to awk with `-v`. There is no need to pass them to shell at all if shell is not used. If more sophisticated functionality would be needed, the output from the program could be manipulated with other programs or scripts anyway. In any case, the answer we are commenting on doesn't work _for the supplied data_.

Comment: That's one of my points - if we use a shebang then the CALLER of the script would need to know that it's implemented in awk to pass parameters to it using `-v`, that's bad software. What if I want to add a "help" option to my tool - should the user need to call it with `-v help` instead of `--help` like in every other Unix tool because it's using an awk shebang? If not, I have to change my shebang and my callers may need to change how they're already calling it as a consequence (e.g. if they use `-v` for other things). The answer we're commenting on works just fine as far as I can see.

Comment: Interesting, because on two of the machines I tested it on (both using GNU awk and mksh, one Artix and the other Alpine) both the original script and the modified one give the incorrect output I linked.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't see the site you linked as it's blocked for me but just reading the code (I've been using awk for 30+ years and Unix for 40+ so I've got a decent grasp of the nooks and crannies) I can't imagine how it could not work. Maybe when you copy/pasted the input your editor added CRs at the end of the lines so it just looks like the script isn't working?

Comment: @Vilinkameni does the script [I posted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/754165/133219) work for you?

Comment: Yes, your script does work. And no, there are no CRs in the file. I use vim under Alpine and Artix.

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas, sorry.

Comment: About accessing the links I posted, they are served as plain text on ix.io and can be retrieved by using curl: `curl http://ix.io/4DwV` and `curl http://ix.io/4DwX`.

Comment: I found out the culprit. It was the first regex. When that line was pasted into vim, the end of that line, `...[0-9]/ {` was broken into two lines at space: `...[0-9]/` and `{` on the next line. This is interpreted by awk as a regex without an action, followed by an action without a regex. I can now confirm that this answer works as well.

Answer (score 1):

Using any POSIX awk:

```
$ awk -F'^[[:space:]]+' '
    NF==1 { if (NR>1) print rec; rec=$0; next }
    { rec = rec OFS $2 }
    END { print rec }
' file
08/07/2023 09:02:07      ANR8592T Session 137576 connection is using protocol TLSVI3, cipher specification TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, certificate TSM Self-Signed Certificate. (SESSION: 137576)
08/07/2023 09:02:07      ANR@B4OT Session 137576 started for administrator ADMIN (WinNT) (SSL MU-SV-SPS1.de.bertrandt.net[192.168.171.56]- :65234) on MU-SV-SPS1.de.bertrandt.net:1500. (SESSTON: 137576)
08/07/2023 09:02:07      ANR2017T Administrator ADMIN issued command: select status from processes where process="NAS SnapMirror Backup’ and status like 'WMU-SV-CL2%' (SESSION: 137576) 08/07/2023 09:02:07 ANR@46ST Session 137576 ended for administrator ADMIN (WinNT). (SESSION: 137576)
08/07/2023 09:02:38      ANR8592T Session 137577 connection is using protocol TLSVI3, cipher specification TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, certificate TSM Self-Signed Certificate. (SESSION: 137577)
08/07/2023 09:02:38      ANR@B4OT Session 137577 started for administrator ADMIN (WinNT) (SSL MU-SV-SPS1.de.bertrandt.net[192.168.171.56]- :65235) on MU-SV-SPS1.de.bertrandt.net:1560. (SESSTON: 137577)
08/07/2023 09:02:38      ANR2017T Administrator ADMIN issued command: select node_name, filespace_name, BACKUP_START, BACKUP_END, CAPACITY, PCT_UTIL from filespaces where node_name like “MU-SV-CL2%" (SESSION: 137577)
08/07/2023 09:02:38      ANR@46ST Session 137577 ended for administrator ADMIN (WinNT). (SESSION: 137577)
08/07/2023 09:02:38      ANR8592T Session 137578 connection is using protocol TLSVI3, cipher specification TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, certificate TSM Self-Signed Certificate. (SESSION: 137578)
08/07/2023 09:02:38      ANR@B4OT Session 137578 started for administrator ADMIN (WinNT) (SSL MU-SV-SPS1.de.bertrandt.net[192.168.171.56]- :65236) on MU-SV-SPS1.de.bertrandt.net:1560. (SESSTON: 137578)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one-line solution using `sed`

```
sed -E -z 's/\n([ ]{25})//g' ./input.txt > ./output.txt
```

- `-E` specify that we will use regular expressions
- `-z` to match `\n` characters
- `s/\n([ ]{25})//g`

  - `s/` to replace
  - `\n([ ]{25})/` to replace a line return followed by 25 spaces by nothing
  - `/g` to execute the action globally on the content

Comment: Why do you use `dos2unix` ? `dos2unix` do not remove `\r` characters but replace `\r\n` by `\n`. Single `\r` characters are not removed. Test with: `echo $'a\r\nb\rc' | dos2unix | cat -e`

Comment: The question doesn't require converting text from DOS/Windows, so there is no need for `dos2unix` (which often isn't even installed by default on many distributions). Also, `\n` is not matched by sed unless you add a `-z` parameter, which also makes `N;` not needed. Other than that, you can just use `sed ... <input.txt >output.txt` instead of `cat input.txt | sed ... >output.txt`. (This is often referred to as ["useless use of cat"](https://porkmail.org/era/unix/award).)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I edited the answer with your comments

Comment: Regarding `Here is a one-line solution in bash:` - That's not bash, it's sed, a completely different tool from bash that you could call from any shell. Note that that script does require GNU sed for `-z`, it won't work in any other sed, and it does require the whole input file to be read into memory at once. Regarding `[ ]` - blanks are already literal, there's no need to put it in a bracket expression.

Answer (score 0):

Using `fmt`:

```
$ fmt -tw 2500 file
```

From `fmt` manual:

> -t, --tagged-paragraph

> indentation of first line different from second

This solution works, until the combined length of merged lines surpasses 2500 characters.

Comment: What does the `-t` option do to your `fmt` command?  On my system, `-t` takes a numerical argument (the width of a tab).

Comment: On Alpine (with GNU coreutils installed), fmt(1) states: `-t, --tagged-paragraph indentation of first line different from second`